# Is the Shenzhou-11 crew's capsule just launched windowless?

Tags: capsule, shenzhou, spacecraft-window

It appears that the crew capsule in today's launch of the Shenzhou-11 crew has no windows.

Windows present a lot of design tradeoffs, but can come in handy in some situations. Is this capsule windowless?

[image]

[image]

**above x2:** from http://www.cctv-america.com/2016/10/14/heavenly-vessel-chinas-shenzhou-11-ready-for-liftoff

[image]

**above:** screen capture from the YouTube video [Launch of Manned China Mission with Shenzhou 11 to Tiangong-2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Jhx4J2j_kw).

Comment: I've been waiting for the day when designers realise that a few (swivellable) high def. cameras can do most of what a window can do, and some things it can't (e.g. protection from extremely bright flashes of light), with less hassle!

Comment: @AndrewThompson an interim  solution would be [Transparent Aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_materials#Transparent_aluminum), until Earth can afford [General Products hulls](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/128375/51174) of course. :-)

Comment: Apollo had a similar cover called the Boost Protective Cover that flew away when the abort tower was jettisoned. I'd imagine this is the same.

Comment: @AndrewThompson windows do not go opaque when their power supply fails.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Each approach has both benefits and down sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly there is a window. Upper left, watch lighting change within the capsule and on astronaut's face after fairing separation.

[image]

**above:** GIF made from screen captures from the following YouTube video: